# Is there a better alternative to PureMVC for Flash projects?

Tags: flash, model-view-controller, puremvc

I used PureMVC in a prior Flash (**not** Flex) project. After adjusting to its requirements, it worked well, but I'm left feeling that it was too over-engineered and cumbersome. I noticed that [Mate](http://mate.asfusion.com/) had lots of positive reviews due to its clarity and simplicity, but it is only for Flex projects, not Flash.

Would it be simpler/clearer to just maintain my own separation of MVC without a framework like PureMVC in Flash, or are there any better alternatives to PureMVC?

Edit: The only lightweight contender I found was [flashMVC](http://www.jadbox.com/flashmvc/).

Answer (score 2):

Do you need a hammer, a mallet, or a shoe?

There is no one answer.. A framework is only as good as it's intended utilization.

what I'm saying is it's ok that there isn't ONE ultimate solution. take it project by project. I've been coding AS since AS first existed and have spun my wheels on these questions only to find there is no one objective answer other than that.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could try Gaia (http://www.gaiaflashframework.com/).  It's more of a front-end framework, but I'm sure its better than nothing.  You could build a very simple back end that would pair nicely with it.

Could be worth a try.

Comment: Build the backend with backend technologies!
Flash, flex is merely good for controller.

Gaia is great for front end, but backend should be done via AMF.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found PureMVC to be less engineered than most frameworks out there and nicer to jump between Flash and Flex with reusable code. Your best bet is to roll your own if you truly want the "best alternative" but I think a "personal" framework that's built on top of Pure could be very hot (that's what I'm working with right now) ... there are loads though. Check out the OOP frameworks section on this link:

http://www.adrianparr.com/?p=83

Answer (score 0):

You can give [ASAP](http://asapframework.org/wiki/bin/view/ASAP/) a try. It's pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Swiz](http://code.google.com/p/swizframework/).  While the project itself states that it is a Flex framework, there is really only one file that relies on MXMLC (the Beans.mxml file).  This can be reworked into an ActionScript file by following [Aral's example on his weblog](http://aralbalkan.com/1960).

Architecturally, Mate and Swiz are a lot alike in regards to what they offer.  They are both MVC frameworks and share a lot of the same fundamental ideas.  The key differences are really just the implementation details.  For example, in Mate you have an Event map and in Swiz you [Mediate] to handle events.  Mate handles events using MXML tags, Swiz handles events by writing ActionScript event handler methods.  Additionally, in Mate you use Injectors inside of a map for dependency injection and in Swiz you [Autowire].

Answer (score 0):

Although my answer is biased as I am the author of FlashMVC ([www.flashmvc.com](http://www.flashmvc.com)), I do hold that it was made to have the highest flexibility while being as easy as possible to implement. There's one import statement needed and the whole framework is about 3 classes. A hello-world example can be just a couple lines of code as oppose to PureMVC which can be dozens. I have used it on both really small projects to industrial size builds.